# How to remove the bits from this light fixtures

Tags: electrical

[image]How do I remove this light fixture? I've tried twisting it and feels like nothing is happening.
I have tried to pry it off with two screw drivers....I'm afraid to be too forceful coz I may break it. It's definately not a twist off and breaking it off may be my only option!
[image: Light fixture]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Perhaps a closer (and better-lit!) picture would help.

Comment: Try pushing up and rotating CCW. Or it may be just a press fit. Try inserting a screwdriver or pry tool in what appears to be a joint and twisting the screwdriver to see if the lower part comes loose.